# Check for updates in InSpec

Tags: testing, inspec

Is there a way to check for updates for packages in InSpec?

Something like:

```
describe package 'httpd' do

   it { should be_uptodate }

end
```

I can't find any resources to help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such resource. You could submit a PR or parse output relevant to your distro / package manager using command resource.